# correct way to nest Item data in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

What is the correct way to nest Item data?

For example, I want the output of a product:

```py
{
    'price': price,
    'title': title,
    'meta': {
        'url': url,
        'added_on': added_on
}
```

I have scrapy.Item of:

```py
class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    price = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    title = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    url = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    added_on = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
```

Now, the way I do it is just to reformat the whole item in the pipeline according to new item template:

```py
class FormatedItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    meta = scrapy.Field()
```

and in pipeline:

```py
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    formated_item = FormatedItem()
    formated_item['title'] = item['title']
    formated_item['price'] = item['price']
    formated_item['meta'] = {
        'url': item['url'],
        'added_on': item['added_on']
    }
    return formated_item
```

Is this correct way to approach this or is there a more straight-forward way to approach this without breaking the philosophy of the framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE** from comments: Looks like [nested loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#nested-loaders) is the updated approach. Another comment suggests this approach will cause errors during serialization.

Best way to approach this is by creating a `main` and a `meta` item class/loader.

```py
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst


class MetaItem(Item):
    url = Field()
    added_on = Field()


class MainItem(Item):
    price = Field()
    title = Field()
    meta = Field(serializer=MetaItem)


class MainItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MainItem
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()


class MetaItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = MetaItem
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

Sample usage:

```py
from scrapy import Spider
from ..items import MainItemLoader, MetaItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        mainloader = MainItemLoader(selector=Selector(response))
        mainloader.add_value('title', 'test')
        mainloader.add_value('price', 'price')
        mainloader.add_value('meta', self.get_meta(response))
        return mainloader.load_item()

    def get_meta(self, response):
        metaloader = MetaItemLoader(selector=Selector(response))
        metaloader.add_value('url', response.url)
        metaloader.add_value('added_on', 'now')
        return metaloader.load_item()
```

After that, you can easily expand your items in the future by creating more "sub-items."

Comment: oh, that was my initial idea but I was a bit confused with the return types, everything cleared up now. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it and it seems to fail at returning valid results. It seems that when the get_meta is called the parse seems to only take in the keys of metaloader, so results are meta{'url':<2nd field, i.e. 'added_on'>} which is really weird.

Comment: Do you mean that item['meta'] evaluates to `{'url':<2nd field, i.e. 'added_on'>}`?

Comment: code above yields the following: `{'meta': {'added_on': 'now', 'url': 'http://example.com'}, 'price': 'price', 'title': 'test'}`

Comment: This approach isn't valid anymore and generates error while serializing the item. I found that defining the field as ```scrapy.Field()``` and initializing it as a list before populating it with sub-item instances works well.

Comment: I realize this is an old question however it still applies. Is the updated solution to create a dictionary or list of MetaItems and assign them to the meta field using the add_value method or is there another way to do this in scrapy? I have this exact problem.

Comment: Looks like nested loaders is the updated approach. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#nested-loaders

Comment: @CharlesGreen Submitted update to answer based on your comment.

Comment: The `Field(serializer=...)` argument is used by [item exporters](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html), and must be a function that returns the to-serialize form for that field.  It has nothing to do with loading. Setting `serializer` to an `Item` subclass breaks exporting horribly. Moreover, scrapy's exporter doesn't support recursive `Item` structures.

Comment: @CharlesGreen can you elaborate what you mean? *Looks like nested loaders is the updated approach. doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#nested-loaders – 
Charles Green
 Jun 9, 2017 at 7:02*

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be more straightforward to construct the dictionary in the spider. Here are two different ways of doing it, both achieving the same result. The only possible dealbreaker here is that the processors apply on the item['meta'] field, not on the item['meta']['added_on'] and item['meta']['url'] fields.

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['meta'] = {'added_on': response.css("a::text").extract()[0]}
    item['meta']['url'] = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()[0]
    return item
```

Is there a specific reason for which you want to construct it that way instead of unpacking the meta field ?