# Scrapy/ item loader / How to load items in order?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to scrap the following a map coordinates , and I have the coordinates as var Data = {lat: 45.000000 , long : 68.00000}

I am able to scrap the above data items 'lng':68.0000 and 'lat':45.0000 as separate items.
and a also put them in a new Key "loc" as 'loc':{'lat':45.0000 ,long: 68.000000}. I am trying to store these scraped items in to MongoDb . In Mongodb ,I need the  'lng and 'lat' values ( coordinates) in a particular order So the Mongodb will recognize them as Geo locations. Mongodb needs 'lng' first and followed by 'lat'.

How do I do that?. Can some one help me?.

This is my Item file

```
class Citylist(scrapy.Item):
    lng = scrapy.Field()
    lat = scrapy.Field()
    loc = scrapy.Filed()
```

This my spider file

```
for newlist in HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('/html/body'):  
    l = ItemLoader(item=Citylist(),response = response)
    l.add_xpath('lng', '//......text()')
    l.add_xpath('lat', '//......text()')
    l.add_value('loc', {'lng': l.get_output_value('lng'), 
                'lat': l.get_output_value('lat')})

    yield l.load_item()
```

My current out put is .....

```
   'lng':'68.00000',
   'lat':'45.00000',
   'loc':{'lat':'45.00000','lng':'68.00000}.
```

1) I need my  out put to be  only .....

```
'loc':{'lng':'68.00000 ,'lat':'45.00000'},
```

I do not need .....

`'lng':'68.00000',  'lat':'45.00000',`

as separate  values. Please advise how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing: here's a good answer about how to properly handle nested data in scrapy https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096896/2446893
Second thing: if order is important, you can use an OrderedDict https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.

You can also use a tuple to return only the values, not the keys.

Comment: Hi Arthur,Yes the order of the nested items are important. I need lng first and then lat values as this the order that will work with mongodb