# scrapy: Populate nested items with itemLoader

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this object I'm trying to populate with an itemLoader:

```
{
  "domains": "string",
  "date_insert": "2016-12-23T11:25:00.213Z",
  "title": "string",
  "url": "string",
  "body": "string",
  "date": "2016-12-23T11:25:00.213Z",
  "authors": [
    "string"
  ],
  "categories": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    "string"
  ],
  "stats": {
    "views_count": 0,
    "comments_count": 0
  }
}
```

Here's my items.py

```
class StatsItem(scrapy.Item):
    views_count=scrapy.Field()
    comments_count=scrapy.Field()

class ArticleItem(scrapy.Item):
    domain = scrapy.Field()
    date_insert=scrapy.Field()
    date_update=scrapy.Field()
    date=scrapy.Field()
    title=scrapy.Field()
    url=scrapy.Field()
    body=scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=Join())
    date=scrapy.Field()
    authors=scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=Identity())
    categories=scrapy.Field(
        output_processor=Identity())
    tags=scrapy.Field()
    stats=scrapy.Field()
```

Part of my spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    loader = ArticleItemLoader(response=response)
    parsed_uri = urlparse(response.url)
    domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)

    loader.add_css('authors','span.meta-author')
    loader.add_css('title', 'h1.title-article')
    loader.add_value('url', response.url)
    loader.add_xpath('date_insert', '//div[@class=\'meta\']/time[@itemprop=\'datePublished\']/@datetime')
    loader.add_xpath('date_update', '//div[@class=\'meta\']/time[@itemprop=\'dateModified\']/@datetime')
    loader.add_value('domain', domain)
    loader.add_xpath('categories', '//ul[@class=\'breadcrumbs\']//li[not(contains(@class, \'home\'))]')
```

So far I have succesfuly populating every fields but "stats". I've checked this page [correct way to nest Item data in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095233/correct-way-to-nest-item-data-in-scrapy) but it seems to not be working anymore (I can't make it work, my error is TypeError: to_unicode must receive a bytes, str or unicode object, got StatsItem)

I'd like to use the itemLoader but I dont see how I could populate my "stats" with my StatsItem

Thx for the help

**Edit**
I am close but it still doesnt work :

```
loader.add_value('stats', self.getStats(response))

def getStats(self, response):
    statsLoader = StatsItemLoader(response=response)
    statsLoader.add_xpath('comments_count', '//div[@class=\'btn-count\']//a/text()')
    statsLoader.add_value('views_count', '42')
    return json.dumps(dict(statsLoader.load_item()))
```

but my output is like :
    {
       [...]
       "stats": "{\"comments_count\": \"0\", \"views_count\": \"42\"}"
    }

Comment: I think you are forgetting to include the `Field(serializer=MetaItem)` in the `stats` attribute for `ArticleItem`

Comment: From the code above are you sure you don't need to provide a `input_processor` and `output_processor` for your `StatsItem` like [this example](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors) from the docs?

Comment: @kiran.koduru I thnik I don't need the `processor` since I set the Item Loader defaults.

Comment: @eLRull I tried `Field(serializer=StatsItem)` but it didn't work

Comment: ok, can you show how are you adding the stats field into your loader (inside the `parse` method).

Comment: this is precisely what i don't know how to do. So far i'm trying `loader.add_value('stats', self.getStats(response))` and the methods itself : `def getStats(self, response):
 statsLoader = StatsItemLoader(response=response)
 statsLoader.add_xpath('comments_count', '//div[@class=\'btn-count\']//a/text()')
 return json.dumps(list(statsLoader.load_item()))`

Comment: just return `statsLoader.load_item()` no need for `json.dumps`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @eLRuLL I manage to find a decent solution :

items.py :

```
class StatsItem(scrapy.Item):
    views_count=scrapy.Field()
    comments_count=scrapy.Field()

class ArticleItem(scrapy.Item):
    [...]
    stats=scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=Identity())


class StatsItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags)
    default_output_processor=TakeFirst()
    default_item_class=StatsItem
```

spider.py:

```
def parse(self, response):
    [...]
    loader.add_value('stats', self.getStats(response))
    [...]

def getStats(self, response):
    statsLoader = StatsItemLoader(response=response)
    statsLoader.add_xpath('comments_count', '//div[@class=\'btn-count\']//a/text()')
    statsLoader.add_value('views_count', '42')
    return dict(statsLoader.load_item())
```

Originally it was not working because my input_processor was     `MapCompose(remove_tags)` for the stats field. In order to serialize the object you have to `return dict(loader.load_item())` and not just `return loader.load_item()`

Thanks !