# Python Scrapy Multilevel Request (Three Level)

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am new to Python Scrapy and I am trying to create JSON file from 3 levels of nested pages. I have following structure:

`Page 1 (start): contains links of second page (called Mangas)
 Page 2: Contains nested Volumes and Chapters
 Page 3: Each Chapter contains multiple images`

My Code

```
import scrapy
import time
import items
import json

class GmangaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gmanga"
    start_urls = [
        "http://gmanga.me/mangas"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # mangas = []

        for manga in response.css('div.manga-item'):
            link = manga.css('a.manga-item-content').xpath('@href').extract_first()

            if link:
                page_link = "http://gmanga.me%s" % link

                mangas = items.Manga()
                mangas['cover'] =  manga.css('a.manga-item-content .manga-cover-container img').xpath('@src').extract_first()
                mangas['title'] = manga.css('a.manga-item-content .manga-cover-container img').xpath('@alt').extract_first()
                mangas['link'] = page_link
                mangas['volumes'] = []

                yield scrapy.Request(page_link, callback=self.parse_volumes, meta = {"mangas": mangas})

    def parse_volumes(self, response):
        mangas = response.meta['mangas']

        for manga in response.css('div.panel'):
            volume = items.Volume()
            volume['name'] = manga.css('div.panel-heading .panel-title a::text').extract_first()
            volume['chapters'] = []
            for tr in manga.css('div.panel-collapse .panel-body table tbody tr'):
                chapter = items.Chapter()
                chapter['name'] = tr.css('td:nth_child(1) div::text').extract_first()
                chapter_link = tr.css('td:nth_child(3) a::attr("href")').extract_first()
                chapter['link'] = chapter_link


                request = scrapy.Request("http://gmanga.me%s" % chapter_link, callback = self.parse_images, meta = {"chapter": chapter})
                yield request

                volume['chapters'].append(chapter)

            mangas['volumes'].append(volume)
        yield mangas


    def parse_images(self, response):
        chapter = response.meta['chapter']
        data = response.xpath("//script").re("alphanumSort\((.*])")
        if data:
            images = json.loads(data[0])
            chapter['images'] = images
        return chapter
```

My Items.py

```
from scrapy import Item, Field
class Manga(Item):
    title = Field()
    cover = Field()
    link = Field()
    volumes = Field()

class Volume(Item):
    name = Field()
    chapters = Field()

class Chapter(Item):
    name = Field()
    images = Field()
    link = Field()
```

Now I am bit confused in `parse_volumes` function where to yield or return to get following structure in json file.

Expected Result:

```
[{
"cover": "http://media.gmanga.me/uploads/manga/cover/151/medium_143061.jpg",
"link": "http://gmanga.me/mangas/gokko",
"volumes": [{
    "name": "xyz",
    "chapters": [{
        "link": "/mangas/gokko/4/3asq",
        "name": "4",
        "images": ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"]
    }, {
        "link": "/mangas/gokko/3/3asq",
        "name": "3",
        "images": ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"]
    }]
}],
"title": "Gokko"
}]
```

But I am getting images node as separate node it must be within chapters node of volume:

```
[{
    "cover": "http://media.gmanga.me/uploads/manga/cover/10581/medium_I2.5HFzVh7e.png",
    "link": "http://gmanga.me/mangas/godess-creation-system",
    "volumes": [{
        "name": "\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062c\u0644\u062f ",
        "chapters": [{
            "link": "/mangas/godess-creation-system/1/ayou-cahn",
            "name": "1"
        }]
    }],
    "title": "Godess Creation System"
},
{
    "images": ["http://media.gmanga.me/uploads/releases/lolly-pop/047-20160111235059UXYGJACW/01.jpg?ak=p0skml", "http://media.gmanga.me/uploads/releases/lolly-pop/047-20160111235059UXYGJACW/02.jpg?ak=p0skml", "http://media.gmanga.me/uploads/releases/lolly-pop/047-20160111235059UXYGJACW/03.jpg?ak=p0skml", "http://media.gmanga.me/uploads/releases/lolly-pop/047-20160111235059UXYGJACW/04.jpg?ak=p0skml"],
    "link": "/mangas/reversal/1/Lolly-Pop",
    "name": "1"
}]
```

Each function is individually fetching data properly, the only issue is JSON formation. It is not writing to json file properly. Please lead me where I am wrong.

Comment: what did you expect ? Show expected result in question. Now it create correctly constructed JSON (exactly with your code) even if it is not what you expected.

Comment: hi @furas, I have updated the question.

Comment: you have to send `mangas` instead of `chapter` to `parse_images`  - `meta = {"mangas": mangas}`. And yield all data in `parse_images` after you append images to chapter. When you `yield Request` it puts request in queue to do it later and it may not wait for your images so `yield mangas` can be executed before you put images.

Comment: or maybe you need [Populate nested items with itemLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333735/scrapy-populate-nested-items-with-itemloader)