# Nested request with same item

Tags: python, scrapy

I have nested requests in different methods that work. The problem is with the use of the Items.
This is my current simplified code:

```
    ...

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "http://example.com"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url)

    def parse(self, response):
        films_urls = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        for href in films_urls:
            yield response.follow(href, callback=self.film)

    def film(self, response):
        film = Film()

        # add url and tmdb_id
        film['list_urls'] = []

        open_stream = response.css('.show::attr(data-href)').extract_first()
        request = response.follow(open_stream, callback=self.streamers)
        request.meta['film'] = film
        yield request

    def streamers(self, response):
        film = response.meta['film']

        urls = response.css('a.aporte::attr(href)').extract()
        for href in urls: # list with all the urls to add to the dictionary
            request = response.follow(href, callback=self.infostream)
            request.meta['film'] = film
            yield request

        yield film #

    def infostream(self, response):
        film = response.meta['film']
        stream = Stream()
        # add lang and web

        redirect = response.css('div.visit a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        request = response.follow(redirect, callback=self.redirect, meta={'dont_redirect': True})
        request.meta['stream'] = stream
        yield request

        film['list_urls'].append(stream)
        return film

    def redirect(self, response):
        stream = response.meta['stream']
        # Any better way to get the redirected url?
        stream['url'] = response.headers['Location'].decode('UTF-8')
        return stream
```

And the items:

```
class Film(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    tmdb_id = scrapy.Field()
    list_urls = scrapy.Field()

class Stream(scrapy.Item):
    lang = scrapy.Field()
    web = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

I'm waiting for a film object that will contain a dictionary with all the available urls. But it never waits for them to be added and returns it empty.

**EDIT:**
If I put "return film" in all methods, it returns the object with the dictionary but every time I add one and not when it is complete.

Comment: maybe it helps: [scrapy: Populate nested items with itemLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333735/scrapy-populate-nested-items-with-itemloader)

Comment: In that case, they don't use more applications. Only one. I don't understand the `ItemLoader`.